# Using previous rows calculated value

Tags: sql-server-2012, cursor, common-table-expression

I have a situation in which I need to set a seed value of a query equal to the first value of another, and use this value to calculate the next row of data (in conjunction with data from the current row). Each subsequent row will need to use the previous rows calculated value.

I've looked into windowed functions e.g. `OVER()` and `LAG()` but I can't seem to get this to work in my situation. A sample of the data is below.

Ultimately I need to take the previous `Inventory`, multiplied by the current row's `AppliedCalc` and add the current row's `Adjustment` field.  This is the new `Inventory` field that will be used in the next row's calculation.

> Inventory = previous [inventory] * [AppliedCalc] + [Adjustment]

`@BeginValue` is the *seed* value the query should be fed.  This value changes, and will be the initial inventory used for future calcs.

```
@BeginValue=1,000,000

DateValue     Inventory    Adjustment     AppliedCalc  
1/31/2001     1000000          0.00         0.00  
2/28/2001     1100125          125.00       1.10  
3/31/2001     1133529          400.00       1.03  
...
```

While I can feed the SQL statement the seed value, I can't perpetuate the calculation to subsequent rows past the second row - I find I need to add an additional subquery for each additional row.  Is there a solution for this beyond using a cursor?

Comment: Can you please share some sample output as well

Comment: The inventory column is the output.  Note the initial 1,000,000 is the seed value, each subsequent row's `Inventory` field is the output.  E.g. 2/28 inventory uses 1/31 inventory of   1,000,000 * 1.10 + 125=1,100,125

Comment: @TT Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've update my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried several things but I could not come up with a *clean* solution. The solution below is a "quirky update". This counts on updates happening following the clustered index. This is not documented, but for at least SQL Server 2005 and up to SQL Server 2012 SP2 (which I've just tested) it works. The general consensus is however: **don't use this way of working for production code** (although I've never seen it *not* working).

Other than that I think you're left to using a CURSOR to do the calculations (see second script). This is a guaranteed safe way.

There may exist other ways of doing this, without a quirky update or using a CURSOR. But I can't come up with one now. HTH!

**Quirky update** (use at your own risk):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(
    date_value DATE CONSTRAINT PK_tt_date_value PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    adjustment DECIMAL(28,2),
    applied_calc DECIMAL(28,2),
    inventory NUMERIC(28,0) CONSTRAINT DF_tt_inventory DEFAULT(0)
);

INSERT INTO #tt(date_value,adjustment,applied_calc)
VALUES
    ('2001-01-31',0.00,1.00),
    ('2001-02-28',125.00,1.10),
    ('2001-03-31',400.00,1.03),
    ('2001-04-30',500,1.05),
    ('2001-05-31',100,1),
    ('2001-06-30',125,1.03);

DECLARE @inventory NUMERIC(28,0) = 100000;

UPDATE
    t1
SET
    @inventory=t1.inventory=@inventory*t1.applied_calc+t1.adjustment
FROM
    #tt AS t1 WITH (INDEX=PK_tt_date_value);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #tt
ORDER BY
    date_value;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

**Using a CURSOR** (safe method):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(
    date_value DATE CONSTRAINT PK_tt_date_value PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    adjustment DECIMAL(28,2),
    applied_calc DECIMAL(28,2),
    inventory NUMERIC(28,0) CONSTRAINT DF_tt_inventory DEFAULT(0)
);

INSERT INTO #tt(date_value,adjustment,applied_calc)
VALUES
    ('2001-01-31',0.00,1.00),
    ('2001-02-28',125.00,1.10),
    ('2001-03-31',400.00,1.03),
    ('2001-04-30',500,1.05),
    ('2001-05-31',100,1),
    ('2001-06-30',125,1.03);

DECLARE c_uv CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT adjustment,applied_calc FROM #tt ORDER BY date_value
    FOR UPDATE OF inventory;
OPEN c_uv;

DECLARE @adjustment DECIMAL(28,2);
DECLARE @applied_calc DECIMAL(28,2);
DECLARE @inventory NUMERIC(28,0) = 100000;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM 
        c_uv 
    INTO 
        @adjustment,
        @applied_calc;

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0
        BREAK;

    SET @inventory=@inventory*@applied_calc+@adjustment;

    UPDATE 
        #tt 
    SET 
        inventory=@inventory 
    WHERE
        CURRENT OF c_uv;
END

CLOSE c_uv;
DEALLOCATE c_uv;

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    #tt 
ORDER BY 
    date_value;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Both scripts give the following result:

```
date_value  adjustment  applied_calc    inventory
2001-01-31  0.00        1.00            100000
2001-02-28  125.00      1.10            110125
2001-03-31  400.00      1.03            113829
2001-04-30  500.00      1.05            120020
2001-05-31  100.00      1.00            120120
2001-06-30  125.00      1.03            123849
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.  What you provide does indeed return what I would want in the first three rows.  I've extended the data a bit by adding additional rows, but this appears to break down in some instances.  Frankly I'm not sure how to tag elements appropriately in the comments section, so I'm adding them to the initial question.

Comment: Thanks TT, I'll test using all three answers and go with the quickest.  I appreciate your time and effort on this!

Comment: You are welcome. I'll keep an eye out for a better solution and if I find one I'll update my answer and let you know. GL!

Comment: Surprising to me, but the cursor was more efficient than the recursive CTE method below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help TT!

I tried using a CTE to answer the question - your proposal may very well be the better option.  Here's what I came up with:

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(
    RowID INT,
    date_value DATE,
    Adjustment DECIMAL(28,2),
    AppliedCalc DECIMAL(28,2)
);

DECLARE @BeginValue Decimal(28,2)=100000;

INSERT INTO #tt(RowID,date_value,Adjustment,AppliedCalc)
VALUES
    (1,'2001-01-31',0.00,1.00),
    (2,'2001-02-28',125.00,1.10),
    (3,'2001-03-31',400.00,1.03),
    (4,'2001-04-30',500.00,1.05),
    (5,'2001-05-31',0.00,1),
    (6,'2001-06-30',1.25,1.03);



;with cteOutput as (
    SELECT t.RowID, date_value, isnull(t.AppliedCalc,1) as AppliedCalc, Adjustment,Cast(@BeginValue as Decimal(28,2)) as AdjMV
        FROM #tt t
        WHERE t.RowID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.RowID, t.date_value, t.AppliedCalc, t.Adjustment,cast((t.AppliedCalc)*cte.Adjmv+isnull(t.Adjustment,0) as decimal(28,2)) as AdjMV
        FROM #tt t
            INNER JOIN cteOutput cte
                ON t.RowID-1 = cte.RowID)



SELECT cte.RowID, cte.date_value,cte.AppliedCalc, cte.Adjustment, cte.AdjMV
    FROM cteOutput cte
    ORDER BY rowid
OPTION(maxrecursion 0)

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

and the output:

```
 RowID  date_value  Inventory   AppliedCalc Adjustment
 1      2001-01-31  100000       1.00        0.00
 2      2001-02-28  110125       1.10        125.00
 3      2001-03-31  113828       1.03        400.00
 4      2001-04-30  120020       1.05        500.00
 5      2001-05-31  120120       1.00        100.00
 6      2001-06-30  123848       1.03        125.00
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for cumulative total,below is the question that has been answered today which uses window functions and works in SQL 2012,my answer is below which works in all versions

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (TypeA int ,  TypeSize int )

INSERT INTO  #temp (TypeA ,  TypeSize)
 VALUES (   110  ,     2),
   ( 110  ,     2),
   ( 110   ,    6),
   ( 200    ,   5),
   ( 200    ,   7),
   ( 301    ,   1),
   ( 301    ,   2),
   ( 301    ,   5),
   ( 301    ,   1)

---accepted answer 
       SELECT TypeA ,  TypeSize, SUM(CAST(TypeSize AS bigint)) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY TypeA ORDER BY TypeA ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Csize FROM #temp AS A 

--my answer
    with cte
    as
    (
    select *,row_number() over (partition by typea order by typea) as rn
    from #temp
    )
    select typea,typesize,(select sum(typesize) from cte t1 where t1.rn<t2.rn+1 and t1.typea=t2.typea
    group by typea
    ) as cszie
    from cte t2
```

Comment: It's not exactly a cumulative total that I want.  How do you perpetuate a calculated column in this solution?  In this solution it appears you're taking the running sum of `TypeSize` where in my situation I would have only the initial `TypeSize` and would need to apply calculations to that original value in each subsequent row.